# Nested Forloop with break condition

Tags: r

Can someone please help me understand the result of below code in R for nesting forloop with break condition:

```
> x=1:3
> y=1:2
> for(i in x){
    for(j in y){
        if(j==2){
            break
        }
        print(j)
    }
    print(i)}

Result:
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 3
```

Comment: Use `cat("j",j)` and `cat("i",i)` for a clearer print.

Answer (score 0):

Be more verbose with the printing statements:

```r
x <- 1:3
y <- 1:2

for (i in x) {
  for (j in y) {
    if (j == 2) {
      break
    }
    print(paste0("Pos: A, i: ", i, ", j:", j))
  }
  print(paste0("Pos: B, i: ", i, ", j:", j))
}
#> [1] "Pos: A, i: 1, j:1"
#> [1] "Pos: B, i: 1, j:2"
#> [1] "Pos: A, i: 2, j:1"
#> [1] "Pos: B, i: 2, j:2"
#> [1] "Pos: A, i: 3, j:1"
#> [1] "Pos: B, i: 3, j:2"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

`breaks` prevents printing at position A anything with j=2. This does not affect printing behavior the position B, because only the innermost loop will be affected by `break`.